# Group not blitting onto screen in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a TDS with `pygame`, and I decided to make a OSD (On Screen Display). This worked and it was on the screen. But it was ugly so I got rid of it. Later on I made a better one, but now it won't blit onto the screen.

I tried using the same code for blitting tiles onto the screen, but it didn't work.
Making and instance of the GUI class doesn't work either.

guis.py

```
class Gui(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y):

        self.groups = game.guis
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((100, 100))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

main.py

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        pg.display.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()

    def draw(self):
        for gui in self.guis:
            self.screen.blit(gui.image, (100, 100))
        pg.display.flip()

    def new(self):
        self.guis = pg.sprite.Group()

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()


g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `Gui` and add the instance to the `self.guis` *Group*:

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def new(self):
        self.guis = pg.sprite.Group()
        gui = Gui(self, 0, 0)
        self.guis.add(gui)
```

In addition I recommend to use [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect` for the position.

Also, don't forget to clear the display before drawing the scene.

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(0)
        self.guis.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was instead of creating a class, I just blitted the images onto the screen.